# Adding vertical space inside lstlisting

Tags: listings, code

I am trying the add empty spaces between two lines in an lstlisting environment.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, frame=single]
      def foo():      
             # I need extra vertical space here
          return x 
\end{lstlisting}
```

***belowskip*** adds space after the listing, **vskip** or **vspace** adds space but it breakes the frame as shown below. **[image: vspace]**

and **lineskip** gives an undesired margin just above the first line, (i.e. **def foo()** ), shown below.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, frame=single, lineskip = 3em]
    def foo():

        return x
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tcolorbox` and `escapechar`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse,listings}

\NewTCBListing{framedlisting}{O{}}
 {%
  boxrule=0.4pt,
  colback=white,
  colframe=black,
  sharp corners,
  listing only,
  listing options={#1},
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{framedlisting}[language=Python,escapechar=$]
def foo(): $\vspace{3\baselineskip}$
return x
\end{framedlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I edited... But still prefer your simples solution... (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Just adding empty lines between the lines you want the extra space will
solve your problem. (In verbatim-litsing environments empty lines DOESN'T MEAN PARAGRAPH START BUT-> EMPTY LINE):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

 \begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, frame=single]
      def foo():      
             # I need extra vertical space here



      return x 
\end{lstlisting} 

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**Edit (A solution with tikz):**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%opening
\title{}

\author{}
\def\tikzmark#1{\tikz[overlay, remember picture]\coordinate(#1);}

\lstnewenvironment{frlstlisting}[1][]{\noindent\tikzmark{A}\lstset{#1}}
{\hspace{\fill}\tikzmark{B}%
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \draw[very thick] ([xshift=-3.7pt,yshift=-7.6pt]A)rectangle([xshift=4.2pt, yshift=14.pt]B);}

\begin{document}



\begin{frlstlisting}[language={Python},escapeinside={/@}{@/}]
def foo():     
/@\vspace{20pt}@/
    return x
\end{frlstlisting}

\begin{frlstlisting}[language={Python},escapeinside={/@}{@/}]
def foo():     
/@\vspace{70pt}@/
    return x
\end{frlstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

The frame is there that would be with framed option (after manually setting the spaces)

Comment: that was my current solution, upped your answer but expecting a programmatic answer.

Comment: Do you want a vertical space after any line? or just manually added (by using `\vspace*` for exmaple)?

Comment: manual is better